# How can i get rid of 0xFEEFEE in VC

Tags: c, visual-c++

I m programming C  for an  assingment in VC++ 2008. I  simulate adjList for  graph implementation. i can readly add edge between two vertex and print the graph.
and i want to remove edge  between two vertex and print the graph again. whatever i do,i cant print the graph after deleting the edge. i get 0xfeefee :( what is this? and how can i resolve this program.

my delete function and print the graph function are illustrated  below.

```
  void deleteEdge(Graph G, Vertex V, Vertex W)
{ 
 Edge list,prev,temp;
 list=V->list;  
  prev=NULL;
  // 
  while(list!=NULL && list->to->value!=W->value){
   prev=list;
   list=list->next;
  }
  // have found the element.
  if(list!=NULL){
   temp=list;
   // if first element of list is deleted.
   if(prev==NULL)
   list=list->next;
   else
   prev->next=list->next;

   // reallocate.
   free(temp);

  }
}




    void GRAPHprint(Graph G)
    {
     Vertex tmp;
     Edge list;
     for(tmp = G->head;tmp!=NULL;tmp=tmp->next)
     {
      fprintf(stdout,"V:%d\t",tmp->value);
      list=tmp->list;
      while(list!=NULL)
      {

       fprintf(stdout,"%d\t",list->to->value);
       list=list->next; 

      }
      fprintf(stdout, "\n");
     }
     system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: `0xfeeefeee` is a flag with which freed memory is filled when running a debug build on Windows (see http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, if you match and hence try to remove the first edge of the list then you will end up dereferencing a pointer which you have freed.

`list=list->next` should be `V->list=list->next`, otherwise you are actually only updating your local list (`list`) rather than the input's list (`V->list`).

The `0xfeeefeee` indicates that you are reading deleted memory on the heap, i.e. that you are dereferencing a pointer on which you have earlier called free. This only happens in debug mode, it's intend to help you catch this kind of problem! See this [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) for more information on this magic number (and others).

Answer (score 1):

When the edge you delete is the first element in `V->list`, this `V->list` pointer will keep pointing to the freed element.

The `prev==NULL` case is trying to handle this problem, but you only advance the temporary local `list` pointer to the next element. You should change `V->list` instead to adjust the main data structure.